# Vim regular expression to match string with prefix and suffix

Tags: regex, vim

I want to search a string which starts with "abc" and ends with "xyz" in vim.

Below are the commands I've tried:

```
:1,$g/abc[\w\W]*xyz/
:1,$g/abc\[\\w\\W\]\*xyz/
:1,$g/abc*xyz/
```

"[\w\W]*" means the texts between "abc" and "xyz" can be any characters

"1,$" means the search range is from the 1st line to the last line in the file opened by vim.

I found that the search pattern

```
abc[\w\W]*xyz
```

works in https://regex101.com/

why does it fail in vim?

Comment: use dot instead of [\w\W]

Comment: There are some difference between Vim's regex and PCRE used by [regex101](http://regex101.com).  For more detail you can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864467/whats-the-difference-between-vim-regex-and-normal-regex).  However, I am not sure if `[\w\W]` is one of them.

Comment: Vim does support *some* character classes inside collections, but only a limited subset (for instance `[[:alpha:]]` works, but `[\w]` does not). You can see `:help /[]` for the supported character classes.

Comment: You may want to add `set incsearch` to your .vimrc.  This will allow you to construct regular expressions and see the matches as you type them (using `/`, not `:global`).  This helps me build more complicated regular expressions since you know where you go wrong instantly instead of having to type out the whole thing and then guess.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The command below should work unless "any character" means something different for you than for Vim:

```
:g/abc.*xyz
```

- `.` means "any character except an EOL".
- `*` means "any number (including 0) of the previous atom".
- `1,$` could be shortened to `%`.
- `:global` works on the whole buffer by default so you don't even need the `%`.
- The closing `/` is not needed if you don't follow `:g/pattern` by a command as in `:g/foo/d`.

Comment: why are we using `:global` here.  just out of curiosity.  Just using the search `/abc.*xyz` works.  plus, if the user has `incsearch` set, they can see their search as they type it using `/`, but not using `:global`.  Just to clarify, there's nothing _wrong_ with using `:global`, just seems odd to me.

Comment: @W.B.Reed, I use `:global` because that's the example given by the OP. Note that `:global` and `/` have vastly different purposes: `/` and `:global` are not interchangeable at all.

Comment: Oh agreed.  It just seemed that the OP was asking to search for a string.  As such, `/` seems more appropriate.  If they just wanted to search for a string, then `/regex` seems more appropriate than `:g/regex`.  `:g` is more appropriate when you want to _do_ something with those matches.

Answer (score 8):

Once the file gets too large (say, 1GB), ":g/abc.*xyz" becomes quite slow.

I found that

```
cat fileName | grep abc | grep xyz >> searchResult.txt
```

is more efficient than using the search function in vim.

I know that this method may return lines that start with "xyz" and end with "abc".

But since this is a rare case in my file(and maybe this doesn't happen quite often for other people), I think I should write this method here.

Comment: I use this approach too, often with long log files. You can then pipe the output (of either of the two greps) to sed to select only the "abc.*xyz" cases

Answer (score 1):

It seems that inside the collection syntax `[..]`, character classes such as \w [can't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276548/3026489), probably because it tests via character-by-character strategy. From `:h  /[]`:

> Matching with a collection can be slow, because each character in
>         the text has to be compared with each character in the collection.
>         Use one of the other atoms above when possible.  Example: "\d" is
>         much faster than "[0-9]" and matches the same characters.

You can, however, use similar functionalities specifically prepared for `[..]` syntax. From `:h /[]` again :

> A character class expression is evaluated to the set of characters
>         belonging to that character class.

examples include:

```
[:alnum:]     letters and digits                   
[:alpha:]     letters                              
[:blank:]     space and tab characters             
[:cntrl:]     control characters                   
[:digit:]     decimal digits                       
[:graph:]     printable characters excluding space 
[:lower:]     lowercase letters
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find them one by one you can hit

`/`

and then write

`abc.*xyz`

and hit enter to find the first occurrence of the pattern. Then use `n` for the next occurrence and `Shift + n` for the previous one. This is how I usually do, since for me this is easier to modify those lines.